# add legend labels to bar graph of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I would like to add cluster names to the stacked barplot in ggplot.

[image]

As you can see, some clusters had very small fraction, and there are many clusters in each bar. This makes it challenging to see which clusters are which, especially between similar colors.
Ideally I would like to selectively label some big fractions (or cluster) with its name,
say when the percentage is > 5%, show its cluster name.

For example, in the sample 'naive CD8 T', I want to label the clusters 4 and 5, like this:

[image]

```
cluster.count %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Cell_subtype,y=count1, fill= seurat_clusters)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'fill')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be achieved like so:

1. Instead of making use of `position="fill"` I compute the percentages manually via `group_by + mutate`
2. The labels could then be easily added via a `geom_text` where you can use an `ifelse` to display only labels with a desired minimum frequency or proportion.

Making use of some random example data try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)
cluster.count <- data.frame(
  Cell_subtype = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 60, replace = TRUE),
  seurat_clusters = sample(0:16, 60, replace = TRUE)
)
cluster.count <- count(cluster.count, Cell_subtype, seurat_clusters, name = "count1")
cluster.count <- mutate(cluster.count, seurat_clusters = factor(seurat_clusters))

cluster.count %>% 
  group_by(Cell_subtype) %>% 
  mutate(pct = count1 / sum(count1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Cell_subtype,y=pct, fill= seurat_clusters)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(pct > .1, as.character(seurat_clusters), "")), position = position_stack(vjust = .5))
```

[image]

Comment: there was a mismatch between the label on the graph and the legend label, and the difference was a constant: 1. For example, in Sample 'D', the top cluster should be 0 not 1.

Comment: Aw. Sorry. That was introduced by converting your variable `seurat_clusters` to a factor (to get a discrete scale and to get the order right). I just made an edit to fix this by using `as.character(seurat_clusters)` in geom_text.

Comment: Thanks! That is interesting. Could you explain why this happens? I thought the conversion between factor and string character (or numeric) would not actually change its value.... I also tried as.integer(seurat_clusters) -1, which makes it work

Comment: When converting to a factor R assigns new numeric values starting with 1, while the original values are stored in the levels attribute, e.g. as.numeric(factor(0:5)) will give you 1:6. Unfortunately that's what's happening in the ifelse, i.e. the factor is converted to a numeric and then to a character. Hence we get the + 1. Using as.character fixes this, as in that case the values are replaced with the original values stored in the levels attribute, i.e. as.character(factor(0:5)) gives you 0:5.